# Illustrator: Resizing multiple objects proportionally by specific values

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, transform

Is there a way (script) to resize multiple objects proportionally in Illustrator by a specific width or height? Illustrator only does it by percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set percentage in preferences? In transform panel you should have 4 values. X and Y values of set point of the object (or group of them) and (in my case) width and height. If you have "link" selected, changing one value will also change the other one.

You should also see this in the upper/lower bar when in it's option menu you tick the "transform".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know scripting but I know if you select several objects together you can enter new height and width transform values that work on all at once.